# How to make sure that elements in div shouldn't cross the div horizontally?

Tags: html, css

We are trying to create a chatbot application. The input where user enters the text and 'send' button are inside a div. The div width is 100%. This is working good in the laptop and on all the mobiles except Iphone14 where the send button is getting cutoff. Below is the code.

```css
.chat-container {
  background: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid #d8dada;
  border-left: 1px solid #d8dada;
}

.chat-container>div:last-of-type {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

body>div>div>div:nth-child(2)>span {
  background: #dadada;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 21px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

body>div>div>div.message-data-right.macro {
  margin: auto;
  margin-left: 1%;
}

.chat-header {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 3.5rem;
  line-height: 3.5rem;
  color: #000000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  position: relative;
}

.chat-header-content {
  align-content: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.header-img {
  height: 24px;
  width: 106px;
  transform: scale(0.85);
  vertical-align: middle;
  content: url('./../images/vz_logo.svg');
}

.gray-button {
  background-color: #5b5b5b;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 24px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Roboto-Medium;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.chat-ul {
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 18px 18px 3px 18px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 62px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  top: 3.5rem;
  overflow-y: auto;
  scrollbar-width: thin;
  scrollbar-color: #909296 #dee0e2;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  margin-bottom: 0%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
}

.entered-text {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #f6f6f6;
  width: 100%;
  border-color: #c1c1c1;
}

.text {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.text>p:first-of-type {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  line-height: 13px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.text>p {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  line-height: 13px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.text>p:last-of-type {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  margin-bottom: -2px;
  margin-top: auto;
}

.text-right {
  float: right;
  font-family: Arial;
  position: relative;
}

.send-message {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

button,
button:focus,
button:active {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat-container">
  <header class="chat-header">
    <img class="header-img" />
    <button type="button" class="icon-close" onClick="closeChatWindow()"></button>
  </header>

  <ul class="chat-ul"></ul>
  <div>
    <div class="send-message">
      <div class="text text-right">
        <input class="entered-text" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <button id="send" class="gray-button" type="button" onClick="onMessageSend()"> Send </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Our testing team raised a bug saying that send button gets cutoff on IPhone14. I am not sure how to reproduce the issue as I don't have Iphone14. I have Android phone on which code is working fine. On Pc also, I tested on different browsers all are working fine. I used toggle device toolbar under developer tools to check how it looks like for different devices and used responsive to change width and height. I am not able to reproduce the issue. Below is the image where it got reproduced on Iphone14.

[image]

At the end of the image 'Send' grey color button is cutoff. Can any one please let me know how to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an iPhone to see this. It's apparent in Chrome for me. Use the emulator in the dev tools if you like.

1. Remove the float (`.text-right`) from the layout
2. Take the 100% width off the input and `.send-message`
3. Move the flex class up a level to contain both the input and the button

I've also added some left margin to the button.

I've fixed a great many such situations in my career, and more often than not the solution involves removing unnecessary styling to simplify. You might work though your entire layout and do so.

```css
.gray-button {
  background-color: #5b5b5b;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 24px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Roboto-Medium;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.entered-text {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #f6f6f6;
  border-color: #c1c1c1;
}

.text {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.send-message {
  border-radius: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

button,
button:focus,
button:active {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat-container">
  <div class="send-message">
      <div class="text">
        <input class="entered-text" />
      </div>
    <button id="send" class="gray-button" type="button" onClick="onMessageSend()"> Send </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way to solve this is to is use the CSS `calc()` function to give `input.entered-text` a flexible `width` which will always accommodate the `width` of the `<button>`:

**e.g.** If you give `button#send` a fixed width (`width: 100px`), *then* you can give `input.entered-text` a width that can accommodate that fixed width (`width: calc(100% - 100px)`)

**Example:**

```
#send {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 12px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.entered-text {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 12px - 100px);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rounin. Is there any reason why it is working on other devices. And also, Do we need to assign the calc function for input class 'entered-text' or for the div which contains the input.

Comment: @kadina - Re: _"Is there any reason why [...]"_ Yes. Form elements like `<button>` have their own `width` according to Operating System and browser. In this case, you need to explicitly declare the `width` of the `<button>` or else it won't be the same from one device to another.

Comment: @kadina - Re: _"Do we need to assign the calc function [...]"_ You need to assign `calc()` to whichever element is the immediately preceding sibling to `button#send`.

Comment: Calculated widths are rarely needed with flex layouts.

Comment: You can use `CSS Flexbox` here. Alternatively you can use `CSS Grid`. I like them both. But you don't need to use either.

Comment: Flexbox is already present and somewhat applied. It just needs to be fixed up. Calc() as you've used it assumes a known button width, which is a fragile approach.

Comment: `CSS Tables` are a fourth alternative. `CSS Percentages` are a fifth alternative. What a lot of alternative approaches we have available to us.

Answer (score 0):

Im no expert but should you put a `<br>` in the div

edit:
line breaks are usually unnecessary so I would say only use this temporary until you find the solution

Comment: Line breaks are usually unnecessary. Don't use them for layout.

Comment: Downvoted because it's not at all clear what "the div" means. Please copy the snippet to your answer and make the changes you're describing.